# Leaflet fitbounds display:none (Bootstrap5 tabnav)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Trying a lot of hours experimenting loading a Leaflet map 'behind' a tab (display:none), when a page is loading.
I know it's nessecary to use **invalidateSize()**.

Okay, with invalidateSize(), it works for loading the Leaflet map after click on the tab 'Kaartweergave'.

The problem are fit the map to the '**bounds**'.

When adding this in my Leaflet-script:

```
setInterval(function () {
 mymap.invalidateSize();
 mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
}, 100);
```

It works, BUT, when trying zoom **[+]** or **[-]**, then after 100ms the map will be reset by the **setInterval**-function.
So trying **setTimeout**-function (onetime-loading):

```
setInterval(function () {
 mymap.invalidateSize();
}, 100);

setTimeout(function () {
 mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
}, 100);
```

But the setTimeout-function doesn't work.

For better explanation and see the complete code, go to this [test-webpage](https://bludit.dogvalley.be/provincie/antwerpen) and click on the tab 'Kaartweergave'(see the source-code).

Hope someone can help me out, i spent a lot of time with experimenting and surfing the internet/Stackoverflow, founding a solution, but with no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on the click event of the tab and then call the map functions:

```
function startMap(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    mymap.invalidateSize();
    mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
  }, 200)
}
var mapTab = document.getElementById('leaflet-map-tab')
L.DomEvent.on(mapTab,'click',startMap)
```

No need for the `setInterval`

Comment: WOW!! Thanks!!!! works perfect out-of-the-box!!! I spent a lot of hours finding a solution. This is awesome!
My original website https://dogvalley.be/ has a leaflet-map and results 
 side-by-side on desktop; on mobile the leaflet-map shows below the results, and not happy with this layout, so i think is better adding tabs for a better UX. Many many thanks for this solution!!!!! Give extra possibilities 'hide' the map also on other pages. :)